# Join (link) documents in PouchDB

Tags: pouchdb

I am using CouchDB as backend and PouchDB for querying / syncing DBs in a vuejs app.

I have 4 different types of documents all stored in one DB like above:

```
{
  "_id": "patientmed_001",
  "_rev": "1-b892ba78a095627af8aef65ac279cc84",
  "doctype": "patient_medication",
  "patient_id": "patient_001",
  "visit_id": "patvisit_001",
  "medicine_id": "med_001",
  "quantity": "1",
  "startdate": "20180101",
  "enddate": "20180201"
}

{
  "_id": "patvisit_001",
  "_rev": "1-f071319f39f4f5df2a1e8214ccc46453",
  "doctype": "patientvisit",
  "patient_id": "patient_001",
  "visitdate": "20010910",
  "complaint": "fever",
  "doctor_attended": "doctor_001",
  "feespaid": "300"
}

{
  "_id": "med_001",
  "_rev": "1-030b39b7773de39fb6a178d77d3d6461",
  "doctype": "medicine",
  "batch": "001",
  "batchdate": "20010910",
  "expirydate": "20021010",
  "unit": "bottle",
  "type": "pills",
  "vendor": "xyz",
  "curr_stock": "20",
  "cost": "200",
  "lastreplenished": "20180101"
}

{
  "_id": "patient_001",
  "_rev": "1-1772d5ff54c46b15642d0b10e5f3906d",
  "doctype": "patient",
  "FirstName": "Test",
  "LastName": "Patient3",
  "Gender": "Male",
  "DOB": "19401010",
  "Address1": "999, XYZ Street",
  "Address2": "ABC avenue",
  "City": "London",
  "Pincode": "AB1CD2",
  "State": "BlahBlah",
  "Country": "UK",
  "Mobile": "001182919112"
}
```

Is it possible to query in PouchDB to get relevant info from other docs by passing patient_id, similar to joins in RDBMS? (i.e.

```
SELECT PatMed.*, PatVisit.*, Patient.* from Patient P
INNER JOIN PatientVisit PatVisit on P.ID = PatVisit.Patient_ID
INNER JOIN PatientMed PatMed on PatVisit.ID = PatMed.VisitID
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not much familiar with RDBMS and I'm not sure if I get your question, but you can create an index like below.

```
var myIndex = {
  _id: '_design/my_index',
  views: {
    'my_index': {
      map: function (doc) {
        if(doc.patient_id){
          // emit patient_id as key and doc as value
          emit(doc.patient_id, doc);
        }
      }.toString()
    }
  }
};
```

Now you can `PUT` and query the above index to find all docs with a `patient_id` field equal to a certain value:

```
// save the design doc view and the corresponding index
pouch.put(myIndex).then(() => {
  // query the index
  return pouch.query('my_index', {key: 'patient_001'});
}).then(result => {
  // found docs with patient_id === 'patient_001'
  console.log(result)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will give it a try. Actually, I understand there is a pouchdb plugin relational-pouch available to do such joins, but unfortunately it does not work well with Vuejs.

Answer (score 0):

I used approach suggested by user3405291 and got all docs which has patient_id.

Based on doctype, I then pushed items to diff arrays and using a js library, [JinqJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jinq), I joined them to get the required data.

Thanks!